# How are node IDs generated?

Tags: nodes

How are node IDs generated?  Is there a field in the database, like "last node ID", that's incremented each time a new node is created?  What is the data type, and are there limitations, such as a maximum value?

Comment: That question makes me wonder why you need to know the last node NID. Often (not always) when that type of question comes up it is a result of wanting to do something where you think you need to know the last NID but actually there may be a better way to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

`{nid}` is an auto_increment field in the table `{node}` - As all of the nodes are sourced from that one table it's able to keep its serialization. This is part of why UUID is such an important initiative in Drupal 8. It's not straightforward to maintain portability of content across environments for this reason.

The type is `int(10)` also known as unsigned so you're only limited by the data type limit of your preferred database and the disk space on your database server to store all those nodes. If it's MySQL that's 0 up to 4294967295.

Comment: +1. @audiomason, you might want to read up on auto incrementing fields for your DBMS. It is for instance possible to [reset](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-reset-auto-increment) the field.